# How can I find out which of these graphs is position, velocity and acceleration?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone help me with this question?
I need to know which graph represents, position, velocity and acceleration. I know velocity is first derivative and acceleration is the second derivative of position but I can't find the answer.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Remember that when the derivative if positive, the function is increasing (and vice versa).

Comment: I Thought The red function is position, Green is velocity and blue is the acceleration, do you think that's correct?

Comment: If the red function were position, then the velocity would be negative starting a little past 1.0 (since the red function is decreasing here).  But the green function is never negative, so we can't have red position and green velocity.

Comment: The red function has an inflection point somewhere around $2.0$ so its second derivative would need to vanish there, but the blue function doesn't.

Comment: Do you think then the combination Red--> Blue-->Green is correct?

Comment: See my previous comment, just replace `blue` with `green` at the end.

Comment: Are you saying that red is position?

Comment: I thought that it is

Comment: No. Position is green. And since it is increasing its derivative must be positive. So, blue or red?

Comment: But I put G for position, red for velocity and blue for acceleration and the answer was wrong :(

Comment: Red can't be position. Why? It is concave on $(0,1).$ So its second derivative must be negative. But blue and green are positive. If blue is position then since it is decreasing on $(0,1)$ its derivative must be negative. But green and red are positive. So, the only possible answer is green for position.

Comment: @Ayda G-R-B is the correct answer. Multiple choice tests can be wrong sometimes, too ;-) All $3$ curves have inflection points, where the $2^{nd}$ derivative must be $0$. But the only function with a non-trivial $0$ is the blue one, so that must be the acceleration. The function with an inflection point near $1.0$ is the green one, so that must be the position. Which leaves the red function for velocity, which is consistent with the other two (for example, it has a maximum at the point where the acceleration crosses $0$).